# How can I make the scrollbars thicker - in Loki?

Tags: scrollbars

I'd like to make the scrollbars wider on Loki (I assume that is the latest version of elementaryOS), but the thread mentioned below suggests that the solution varies according to the version of elementaryOS. What do I need to do for Loki?

---

I'd add a comment to existing thread [How can I make the scrollbars thicker?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/269/how-can-i-make-the-scrollbars-thicker)
but apparently I need 50 reputation to do so and I haven't got that.

Answer (score 2):

Changing scrollbar widths are the same in Loki as in Freya.  Using sudo permission, edit lines containing "slider-width" in the scrollbar sections of:

```
/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css
```

I changed the settings to 12, but use what looks best to you.

Cheers

Comment: I have tried this, increasing the figure from 12 via 15 and 18 to 23 but it hasn't changed. I don't like the fact that they disappear either.

Comment: For me it worked for most apps after restart. The others overwrite the system setting I guess, or use an own rendering engine.

Answer (score 0):

The change in /usr/share/themes/gtk-3.0/gt-widgets is working for me. Set it at 2 places to 14.

Changes in gtkrc did not have any results.

You have to reboot to see changes.

Would be nice to have the possibility to change this with a gui in the setting. Working in a aeroplane or train is much easier with wider scrollbar, but not so looking cool.

Comment: If this can be placed on an Accessibility switch, it would be great